# Present related objects as strings on JSON responses on a Laravel REST API?

Tags: json, api, rest, laravel, laravel-4

I'm writing a REST API on Laravel and I'm taking advantage of polymorphic relationships. So many resources have tied `images`. When I create the response, using eager loading like this:

```
return User::with('image')->find($id);
```

I get something like this:

```
{
    id: 27,
    image: {
        id: 340,
        url: "https://amazonbucket.com/2lBqWzDme.jpg",
        created_at: "2015-01-28 17:21:17",
        updated_at: "2015-01-28 18:28:42",
    }
}
```

Instead, I want it to be automatically output just the `url` as a `string` like this, so it's easier on the frontend:

```
{
    id: 27,
    image: "https://amazonbucket.com/2lBqWzDme.jpg"
}
```

I tried to work with the `Image::toJson()` method but it didn't work. I Could use the `User::toJson()` method, but I'd had to do it on all the existing/upcoming instances that use `images`. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it happens usually, I found a better, less invasive way of doing this looking for something else:

Just add the `$appends` protected attribute to your model and set the `getImageAttribute()` method.

```
protected $appends = ['image'];  

function getImageAttribute() {
    return $this->images()->first()->url;
}
```

Check the bottom of http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json.

It works like charm!

Answer (score 1):

Overriding the `Image::toJson()` method won't help here. In this case, the truncated call stack would be `User::toJson()` --> `User::toArray()` --> `Image::toArray()`.

So, now the problem becomes that in order to do what you want to do, you would have to override the `Image::toArray()` method so that it no longer returns an array, but instead returns a string containing the url value. I can't imagine this would go over too well, but I've never done it before.

If you're looking to only modify the `Image` class, the closest you could get would be to assign the `Image::visible` attribute to only include the `url` key. This would turn your JSON into:

```
{
    id: 27,
    image: {
        url: "https://amazonbucket.com/2lBqWzDme.jpg",
    }
}
```

Outside of that, you're looking at a solution where you'll need to modify each class that will be imageable. However, you could extract the required functionality out into a Trait or a base class that your other classes extend. In either case, you're looking to modify the `toArray()` method, not the `toJson()` method.

Comment: Nice @patricus! I was already using `Image::visible` to do exactly what you suggest. The last paragraph (the trait) did the trick very smoothly:

`trait GetOnlyUrlOfImagesOnToArrayTrait {
 function toArray() {
  $arr = parent::toArray();
  if (isset($arr['image']['url']))
   $arr['image'] = $arr['image']['url'];
  return $arr;
 }
}`